# Android phone number dial or pick from contacts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, contactpicker, android-dialer

I want the user to be able to send an sms by either dialing a phone number himself or picking it up from a contact list.

I know that I could easily achieve it, querying all the contacts and providing a `TextView` to either filtering the contacts or dialing a number but my question his aimed to simplify the code.

On the default lollipop Messenger app, if the user clicks the "+" plus button, he can do exactly what I've described before: [here's a screenshot of what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/k5lPtuf.jpg).

On Android, there is a pretty similar function which I am able to reproduce using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

However, it only let the user pick up an already existing contact and eventually extracts a phone number from it.

Shortly my question is:
Is there any way to reproduce the default Messenger behavior by using `Intent`s?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: like this: https://codeshare.io/aFQT7 ?

Comment: @pskink thank you for the code, it helps. However this is actually what I'm trying to avoid but from what I see there is no native function to do so.
Thank you.

Comment: "but my question is aimed to simplify the code." what can be simpler than those 20 lines of code (i am not counting the first 8 lines that creates the UI) ?

Comment: Yes in fact I really appreciate the code. I was looking for a way to simply call an intent. I'm starting exactly from you code, but if you have a look at the screenshot I posted, there is much more to build from scratch at least talking about UI.

Comment: so create an Activity for that, like any other choosers do, you would need to call `setResult()` before `finish()` that way you can `startActivityForResult()`